# Can the Angular Injector inject a method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, I know that I can inject services via the dependency injector for a provider that I define (service, controller, etc). I know that I can do something like this:

```
app.factory('myFactory', ['$window', function ($window) {
    // Now I can check properties on Window.

    if (!$window.sessionStorage) throw new Error("message");
}]);
```

But is it possible to do something like this, with the injector?

```
app.factory('myFactory', ['$window.sessionStorage', function ($storage) {
    // Now I can check properties on Window.

    if (!$storage) throw new Error("message");
}]);
```

I'm writing a service and I'd like my dependencies to be swappable on a logical basis, if at all possible, but I don't necessarily want to rely on writing a wrapper for a POJO object.

Thanks!

Comment: not if you don't register it as a provider, service , factory etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually - there is a way to do this, by using `.constant` or `.value`. (From what I understand, `.constant` can be used in a `config` block, while `value` cannot be.) You'd do something like the following:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .value('storage', window.localStorage);
```

...and there you have it.

Alternatively, since providers in Angular kind of suck (and are pretty confusing and hard to remember), it might be easier to just use `.provider` and manually attach something like `window.localStorage` to the `$get` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are trying to do. You would need to create a wrapper service. This would be very simple to do. For session storage there is ngStorage that you could use: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage. By using this you won't have to serialize/deserialize.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of ngStorage and I've written wrappers for services before. I was hoping to avoid it here so that I could allow someone to inject something of their choosing. This is for my library [Memento](https://github.com/jedd-ahyoung/memento) - specifically, window.sessionStorage.